# Plesk Rebranding Web Hosting

Tags: themes, plesk

I recently bought the new Plesk software and im unsure on how to re-brand the site to our company logos and themes.

Does anyone know the steps to changes these settings or a manual that would answer my questions?

Regards,
          Oliver James

Answer (score 2):

Well, it really depends on how much work you want to do. You can do as little as changing the logo--which is quite simple--to as much as completely retheming the interface to match your company's brand. The path of least resistance is to copy an existing skin and modify it to suit your needs.

Either way, start in the admin interface and go to the Server config page. The two options that should interest you are there: Logo Setup and Interface Management. Changing the logo is pretty obvious, so I'll stick to the Interface Management part.

Once in the Interface Management section, click on the Skins tab. The first thing you should do here is find the skin that most closely resembles what you'd like your finished product to look like. You'll notice on the list of skins that there's an icon of a floppy disk; clicking on this icon will allow you to download a .zip or .tar.gz file containing all the files for the skin.

Now you just need to alter the skin as necessary. I recommend setting up a development server (or a virtualized server) where you can play with Plesk without causing any damage to your production server. And, of course, best practices dictate that you should probably put it all under source control to make sure nothing goes wrong.

Anyhow, once you've made your changes and you're satisfied with the results, go back to the Skins page in the Interface Management section and click the Add New Skin button. Zip up your skin (to match the way it was zipped when you downloaded the base skin) and upload the file. Once you've uploaded it, you can then choose the skin from the Skins page. To be on the safe side, I recommend creating a dummy client user and testing out the skin on your production environment before switching any existing users to the new skin, just in case there's a problem with the skin.

And once you're satisfied that your newly-modified skin works on the production site, go ahead and switch all your existing users over.